# Want to check if there is a worksheet with the same name as the file

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

Want to check if there is a worksheet with the same name as the file.

At the moment I have filnam opening the files as an array but want it to cycle through the code and see if there is a worksheet with the same name.

I have used a split to remove the path name and the extension but cant get it to check.

I apologise for the messiness of the code. Been trying to get it sorted then Ill tidy it up. There is more code but that isnt required for this as I want it to run that code if there isnt a match.

Please can you help?

```
Sub sort_it_out()

 Dim wb1 As Workbook
 Dim wb2 As Workbook
 Dim Sheet As Worksheet
 Dim filnam As Variant
 On Error GoTo errorhandler

 Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

 ChDir Application.ActiveWorkbook.path

    'get files
    filnam = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="2D Table Formats (*.htm;*.xlsm;*.html),*.htm;*.xlsm;*.html", Title:="Select 2D Table", MultiSelect:=True)

    'set the array
    If IsArray(filnam) Then 'if at least one file is selected, this will be an Array

    'define j as the array
    For j = LBound(filnam) To UBound(filnam)

    'remove path and extension
    Dim s As String, a() As String, p As String
    s = filnam(j)
    a() = Split(s, "\")
    p = Split(a(UBound(a)), ".")(0)

    MsgBox "p " & p

    'check if worksheet exists
    For Each ws_check In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets()

        If ws_check.Name = p Then
            MsgBox "Its there"
            Exit Sub
            Else
        End If
   Next ws_check

   'continue code from here
```

This then runs the code... but its not looping the array for some reason. Only one file at at a time. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked it all out now.

This will now open file locations, shorten their paths to just the filename minus the extension, then ws check checks the sheets against the filename and then looper jumps to the next.

Thank you to alwaysdata for helping me out.

```
Sub sort_it_out()

 Dim filnam As Variant

 'open file locations
 filnam = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="2D Table Formats (*.htm;*.xlsm;*.html),*.htm;*.xlsm;*.html", Title:="Select 2D Table", MultiSelect:=True)

 'if at least one file is selected, this will be an Array 
    If IsArray(filnam) Then 

    For j = LBound(filnam) To UBound(filnam)

 'remove pathway and extension from entire filename and path. ie C:\open.txt becomes open.

    Dim s As String, a() As String, p As String
    s = filnam(j)
    a() = Split(s, "\")
    p = Split(a(UBound(a)), ".")(0)


 'check if worksheet exists against p ... ie if theres a worksheet called open it will goto the next option if not it will continue through code
    For Each ws_check In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets()

        If ws_check.Name = p Then
            MsgBox p & " has already been transfered across. ", vbExclamation 'lets the user know this is already there.

            GoTo looper
            Else
        End If
   Next ws_check

 'do something here with the code if not found. IE MSGBOX " NOT FOUND "

 'jump to this point if there is a match. 
looper:
Next
    Else
    Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a little hard to follow your code but does this do what you are trying to do?

I think you were storing the file name in the p variable so my code below would check each worksheet in the workbook to see if they have the same name as the p variable.

```
Public Sub CompareWorksheetNamesToFiles()

    Dim file_name As String
    file_name = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    Dim ws_check As Worksheet
    For Each ws_check In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets()

        If ws_check.Name = p Then
            Debug.Print ("Do Something")
        End If

    Next ws_check

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it when I get in. The filnam is what's opening the file into an array. Filnam(j) calls the array then I'm having to shorten it down with p to remove all the additional path information. Would this check each of the files that are opened or just one in p?

Comment: I think I need to define p as an array from filnam if that makes sense

Comment: well your p appeared to be inside a for loop so I was thinking you were going through each file in the array and populating p with the file name. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Hi, the check works well thank you but its not checking the array only one at a time. Is there something im doing wrong?